# Hidden layer in image preview, can't see in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, png

I am a Photoshop novice and so I expect this might be simple to solve but it's a fairly unique problem (I think) and I cannot find a similar issue/solution searching online.

I had a PSD of my logo, when I use `Image -> Trim` to reduce my canvas size around the image I noticed it left some space above the logo, which I thought was weird but couldn't work out why.

I exported the psd to a `.png` format and stuck it on a web page, looks fine so I didn't think too much of it. However, when I open the `.png` in the Windows 10 photo viewer I noticed the hidden shapes in the top left corner. That explains why Photoshop wouldn't trim all the way down to the edge of the visible logo, which means Photoshop can "see" the shapes but I cannot see it.

It's definitely not a layer, hiding/showing everything makes no difference as the shapes never become visible.

The shapes in question are from a very old version of the logo that I thought I deleted properly (as they weren't visible to me on screen) but my PS knowledge not even at a pedestrian level I figure I've somehow left the shape there.

**What I've tried**:

- Changing the PSD background from transparent too black/orage to try and make the shapes visible.
- Using quick selection and magic wand on the area in question. It doesn't pick anything up.

I have a feeling I've broken the "master" PSD at some point and removed a layer that's going to make it impossible to fix.

**Screenshots**:

[image]

^ You can see the canvas won't go down to the top of the blue shape

[image]

^ The Windows 10 photo viewer of the exported PNG that reveals the shapes in the top left corner, - although not visible on a web page or anywhere else that I can see.

I am using Photoshop CC 2015

**EDIT** I colored the foreground blue on all layers and it revealed the squares although I can't remove them, as it looks like they're just transparent boxes? When I fill them there's like a 0.1px feint line that I can just make out but I can't work out how to completely remove it...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those square shapes **are present** in your file. They are just a very low opacity white.

Here's a screen shot with the area blown up. You can see the faint white shapes against the transparency grid. (Look next to the cursor in the screenshot)

[image]

These shapes **must** be on a layer somewhere in the file. You'll need to find them and remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling all layers and saving it as png again.
If the icons are still there, it's def a corrupt file.

To fix that you can try to move all the visible layers into a new file.

If icons are not visible after previewing the fully disabled png, it's most likely the shapes are part of your layer structure and just 'hidden' somewhere in there. Maybe as a merged shape or something.

Comment: I disabled all layers and when I tried to export it was all grayed out because it said the "image was empty" so I presume it's tied into one of the images. I then actually managed to see the shapes in Photoshop by filling the background and then the squares all appeared with a transparent background but it won't let me select them or remove them :/ - I edited my original post with some further info.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the little squares have some alpha/opacity, in that case it will be really hard to notice it even if you change the background, and quick selection/magic wand wont be able to select element that has really low opacity like 2%.

Is you logo a path? If it is, you could try using **Direct Selection Tool (A)** and try selection the whole document.

Comment: I made edit to my OP, not sure if it gives you any more info?

Comment: I see, maybe trying to select only the logo with **Direct Selection Tool (A)** and cut and paste on a new document will get rid of the squares?

Comment: That tool doesn't select anything, just let's me hold to select an area then nothing is selected :/

Comment: So your logo isn't paths? Could you post a print of the layer tab to see what it looks like?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/qXu7Pzy.png - I also just restored the old old original PSD with those squares still on there and the layer is called path + path +path etc... - I had the original logo designed for me, but it seems I can't do much to the layers.

Comment: From that print, i can see that the only thing that is editable is the text layer, correct? you could simple save as png, cut every piece using **Lasso Tool (L)** and remake the .psd. Since i dont see paths, effects and bleding modes etc...

**edit:** Also worth checking the **Paths tab** to see if there's anything in there. But from that print, those layers are rasterized and not paths.

Answer (score 0):

Since the squares are transparent, my money is on a clipping path: check your *paths* palette for any errant paths that need deleting. You should also check your *channels* palette as well, since you can have channels in there that go unnoticed.